# Odd length hex issue when trying to RLP encode transaction

Tags: ethers.js, signature, rlp, sendsignedtransaction

I'm trying to RLP encode a transaction I get from the mempool to get the signed transaction hex using ethersjs.

Here's how the tx looks like initially:

```json
{
  "blockHash": null,
  "blockNumber": null,
  "from": "0x71a218a64d658a3b4dadd11d0bb50047bf25d1db",
  "gas": "0x186a0",
  "gasPrice": "0x28fa6ae00",
  "hash": "0xcc2eed93b30609bb98372992d4403c1cbc17039fe7e1bef5dc54beb93f6e28d8",
  "input": "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000477b8d5ef7c2c42db84deb555419cd817c336b6f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000416a5c67",
  "nonce": "0xe",
  "to": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
  "transactionIndex": null,
  "value": "0x0",
  "type": "0x0",
  "chainId": "0x1",
  "v": "0x26",
  "r": "0x595eca735685a58e520caa7f38854205a300a7979c1c671337372d52c626eab8",
  "s": "0xd80d68a96d8200b38c5f44ad09d843396770a367a7cabce01755896bf717ae6"
}
```

And I try to encode it like this:

```js
const params = [
      tx.nonce,
      tx.gasPrice,
      tx.gas,
      tx.to,
      tx.value,
      tx.input,
      tx.v,
      tx.r,
      tx.s,
];

const encodedSignedTx = ethers.utils.RLP.encode(params);
```

However some of the hex strings like nonce and value are not even length so I keep getting `hex data is odd-length ...` errors.

I tried using `hexZeroPad` but the length is not fixed. How can I force the hex values to be even without adding too many extra zeroes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ethers.BigNumber` to "normalise" all hex values (except the `to` address):

```
const params = [
  ethers.BigNumber.from(tx.nonce)._hex,
  ethers.BigNumber.from(tx.gasPrice)._hex,
  ethers.BigNumber.from(tx.gas)._hex,
  //...
];
```